# How to map java.util.Optional with jersey client

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a DTO with a field of type java.util.Optional, like this:

```
public class Person {

private final Optional<Long> id;

@JsonCreator
public Person(@JsonProperty("id") Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Optional<Long> id {
    return this.id
}
```

}

If I try to serialize it in json format and send it by jersey client, the server throws the exception below:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.util.Optional<java.lang.Long>] from Integral number (1); no single-int-arg constructor/factory method
```

It's possible to use java.util.Optional with jersey client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The json does not contain an optional, it contains a long, so you need to create an `Optional` out of the `Long` you are getting:

```
@JsonCreator
public Person(@JsonProperty("id") Long id) {
    this.id = Optional.ofNullable(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`jackson-datatype-jdk8`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Create an [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance and register the [`Jdk8Module`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jdk8/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

And then register the [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html) in your [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper));
```

Comment: We use drowizard framework, it already made that configuration. Thanks.