# (Why) is Jdk8Module registering "itself"?

Tags: java, tomcat, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I have an implementation using Tomcat v10.0.x and org.glassfish.jersey.* in version 3.0.5 to provide a web service. Initially, I had problems returning response Objects as `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` whenever they hat Attributes/Getters that are `Optional`.

Once I added jackson-datatype-jdk8 2.13.3 based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038232/how-to-map-java-util-optional-with-jersey-client) question, everything started to work fine.

I am confused, though. I did not register `Jdk8Module` because I am not actively creating a `Client` instance. As far as I believe to understand the inner workings of Jersey as JAX-RS implementation, the `@POST` annotations I am using are responsible for handling Client objects. It might also be Tomcat. On the web there is a big gap between simple howtos with little explanation, and in-depth documentation that is hard to understand.

Where is Jdk8Module registered, and how, and why, or not at all? Simply speaking, why does my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: META-INF/services.

**Longer answer**: Jackson defines [Module class](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.14/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.java) which is used as a [service](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.13.3/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L1104) (defined in META-INF/services) loaded by a standard ServiceLoader mechanism. Jackson defines
a static [method loading](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.13.3/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L1088) all `Modules` and the Jackson `jackson-datatype-java8` module defines the [proper service](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/jackson-modules-java8-2.13.3/datatypes/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module).

Jersey just [uses](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.0.5/media/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java#L76) the Jackson service-finding routine to [register the module](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.0.5/media/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java#L62).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry for taking so long to finding time to read and understand your text. There's much information in few sentences. I also had to read https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html and now I think I got it. Edit: replaced link with current LTS version.